# Jqueryui performance optimization

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-ui

I require your assistance, 
I have a quite heavy html page and I want it to be JqueryUI - ed.

I mean transforming check boxes into ui-buttons, radio buttons into jUI radios, etc...
This is in a simple dialog and it takes 25 seconds to render !

Using Chrome developer tools, I can see a lot of Parse HTML calls. All the time is spent on rendering.

Can you give some advices to optimize the Jquery calls ?

Here is the code and below the Chrome result.

```
        $("input[id*=roleHabilitationsListItemAdd]")
        .button({
            icons: {primary: "ui-icon-none"},
            text: false
        })
        .click(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                $(this).button("option", "icons", {primary: "ui-icon-check"});
            }
            else {
                $(this).button("option", "icons", {primary: "ui-icon-none"});
            }
        })
        .filter(":checked").button({icons: {primary: "ui-icon-check"}});
```

[image: This screen show the developer tool and the beginning of all the calls]
[image: This is part of the result, the heavier tab. Another has radio buttons (only one dimention though)]

Comment: This has nothing to do with `php`.